# Cash On Delivery Not Working for Free Shipping Method in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In Woocommerce Settings Page Payments Tab, I Enable Cash on Delivery Payment Option when All Flat Rate and Any Free Shipping Method.

When the Order is Flat Rate Shipping Method, Cash on Delivery Display but, When the Order is Free Shipping Method, Cash on Delivery Not Display. How to enable Cash On Delivery Payment Method.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked into the code where this option is used? Normally this way I find out things like this.

Comment: product which you have added into the cart is all virtual products? b'coz last checkbox saying that allow COD for virtual products

Comment: I think it's not an issue. In Flat Rate Shipping Method COD Display fine. @Janki

Comment: can you please check your function file code for woocommerce_package_rates hook. might be this is happen because it hide other shipping method when free shipping is enable